# How to delete call history details using tableview editing method in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sql-delete

I am new in iPhone application development. I am developing a call history application in iPhone. In this application I am fetching all call details using a call history database, and then displaying in table view. Now I want to perform a delete on the selected row call history value in the database. I don't know how to perform this operation. I am using the following code but it is showing an error like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating delete statement. 'near "<": syntax error''

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [appDelegate.displayHistroryValueAppDelegate removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [displayTableView reloadData];
        int rowId = [[[appDelegate.displayHistroryValueAppDelegate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ROWID"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"rowidvalue: %d", rowId);

        NSString *databasePath =@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";

       // NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM calls WHERE ROWID = %d",rowId];
       // NSLog(@"DELETE statement: %@", sqlStatement);
        sqlite3 *database;

        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            //const char *sql = "delete from reminders where ID = ?";
           //const char *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM call WHERE ROWID = %d",rowId];
            const char *sqlStatement = "delete from call where ROWID = ?";
            sqlite3_stmt *deletestmt;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &deletestmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
            {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }



           // sqlite3_bind_int(deletestmt, 1, [IdValue intValue]);

             sqlite3_bind_int(deletestmt, 1, rowId);

            if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deletestmt)) 
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            sqlite3_reset(deletestmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: I don't think IOS 5 support that functionality. You can't change the call history database.

Comment: I think it is possible to delete call history database. I will search and then do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API in the SDK to access iPhone’s Call History, there is a read-only SQLite database that gives access to the call history see [this Link](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that this is just a temporary fix to delete history on iPhone. As you use your phone, the same type of data will just accumulate again, requiring another restore as new to delete.

If you restore as new, you sync when finished the iPhone Data Eraser, to restore your data. So, if you decide to do this, make sure all of your data is on your computer before you go down this route. Restoring as new returns your phone to a state just like it was when first taken out of the box.